# CakePHP v2.4.3: setDataSource for all Model at once

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am building a synching app for two database which load data from primary db and load to secondary db, now for secondary db operation I am using

```
> $this->Model->setDataSource('second');
```

to load second db and `

> $this->Model->saveAll($put);

to save data in secondary db, now the problem is all data from Model table is going to secondary db but **all associated** data which are link by foreign key goes to primary db.

Comment: Can you help us understand _why_ you are using two separate databases? Maybe we can provide an easier solutions that won't cause as many headaches.

Comment: OK I just want to sync two database one is online and one is offline, not automatically but manually.Also the online database is hosted on Go-daddy(Shared Hosting) and offline database is in xampp.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppModel` just change `$useDbConfig` from `'default'` to the other config. This will change it for all of your models that inherit from `AppModel`, which should be all of them if you're following conventions.

Comment: But I want Switch between those two database in my controller, The AppModel set different database for all instance.